# Variable in function from included file - php

Tags: php, function, variables

I haven't found a very good answer to my problem so I'm starting a new topic. I have the file english.php which has variables like **$lang['fname'] = "First name";**. Also I have header.php which includes english.php : include('english.php');. Now, header.php is included in another php page, let say addInfo.php. If I write in addInfo.php : **echo $lang['fname'];** it shows me "First name", but if i write a function in addInfo.php, as example **function added () { echo $lang['fname'];}** and then added(); (i tried also echo added()) it doesn't want to display the value("First name"). Does somebody know a solution for this sample(i think) problem. I'm ready to try all answers. Regards, StefanZ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you write this :

```
function added () {
    echo $lang['fname'];
}
```

PHP will search for a `$lang` variable that is local to the function :

- it will not see the global one that's declared outside of the function.
- and, as there is no `$lang` variable set, inside the function, `$lang['fname']` will be `null` -- i.e. it will not display anything when `echo`ed.

To indicate to PHP that it should use the global variable from outside the function, **you need to declare the variable as `global`**, inside the function :

```
function added () {
    global $lang;
    echo $lang['fname'];
}
```

For more informations, you should read the **[Variable scope](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) section** of the PHP manual.

Comment: Yep, this can be tricky if you're used to javascript or something where external definitions are automatically allowed in the function scope.

Answer (score 2):

you have to state global $lang in your function

ex.

```
function added(){
   global $lang;

   echo $lang["fname"];
}
```