# I can not access the global variable in function in included file

Tags: php

I can not access the global variable in function in included file

sample files : [dl.dropbox.com/u/9486036/similasyon.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9486036/similasyon.zip)

**simulations:**

**index.php:**

```
<?

function init(){
    include "init.php";
}

init();

?>
```

**init.php:**

```
<?

$data = "data_string";

echo "Data-test in ".__FILE__.": <b>".$data."</b><br />\r\n"; 

include "php/funcs.php";

?>
```

**funcs.php:**

```
<? 

echo "Data-test in ".__FILE__.": <b>".$data."</b><br />\r\n";

function func_load()
{
    global $data;
    echo "Data-test in ".__FILE__." in function func_load(): <b>".$data."</b><br />\r\n";

    include dirname(__FILE__)."/funcs/sub_func.php";
}

func_load();

?>
```

**sub_func.php:**

```
<? 
    echo "Data-test in ".__FILE__.": <b>".$data."</b><br />\r\n";
?>
```

**screen output:**

```
Data-test in \similasyon\init.php                             : data_string 
Data-test in \similasyon\php\funcs.php                        : data_string 
Data-test in \similasyon\php\funcs.php in function func_load():  
Data-test in \similasyon\php\funcs\sub_func.php               :
```

Comment: Not an answer: You can use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable in function from included file - php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412041/variable-in-function-from-included-file-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the initial include is also wrapped in a function and the would need a `global $data` inside it like this in your index.php

```
 function init(){
      global $data;
      include "init.php";
 }
 init();
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about what you are doing for a second. After all the includes are done, you end up with something like this:

```
<?php

function init(){
    $data = "data_string";

    echo "Data-test in ".__FILE__.": <b>".$data."</b><br />\r\n"; 
    echo "Data-test in ".__FILE__.": <b>".$data."</b><br />\r\n";

    function func_load()
    {
        global $data;
        echo "Data-test in ".__FILE__." in function func_load(): <b>".$data."</b><br />\r\n";
        echo "Data-test in ".__FILE__.": <b>".$data."</b><br />\r\n";
    }

    func_load();
}

init();

?>
```

Basically, `$data` is not in the global scope. You'll have to change your `init()` to something like:

```
function init(){
    global $data;
    include "init.php";
}
```

Although you should seriously consider restructuring the code, because this just doesn't look good.

**Especially** having includes within includes when they all belong to the same function body.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `$data` really global to use it everywhere with `global` keyword:

```
function init(){
    global $data;
    include "init.php";
}

init();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change:

```
<?

function init(){
    include "init.php";
}

init();

?>
```

To

```
<?

function init(){
    global $data;
    include "init.php";
}

init();

?>
```

Then it should work.

Comment: See @NullUserException answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662143/i-can-not-access-the-global-variable-in-function-in-included-file/7662333#7662333 for an explanation of why this works.